# Issues updating list elements

Tags: list, data-structures, f#, task-parallel-library

The following function is meant to add parallelism by updating elements of list in chunks, in an attempt to load balance it.  However, its giving me: property 'item' cannot be set at xs.[x1] in the internal loop.  I have to use a list, as the list past to the function is part of a bigger algorithm.  Any suggestions?

```
let pmap_tpl_parforlb f (xs:list<_>) =
    let chunkLength = xs.Length / numProc 
    Parallel.For(0,numProc, fun c ->    
        let x = c * chunkLength
        let y = (c * chunkLength) + chunkLength
        let x1 = x+1
        for x1 in 0..y-1 do
            xs.[x1] <- f (xs.[x1])
    ) |> ignore
    xs
```

Answer (score 2):

The built-in F# list type is immutable, which is why you're getting that error. You can use the index notation (`blah.[idx]`) to access a list value, but it's extremely uncommon and also slow because it's an O(n) operation.

From the snippet of code you posted, it seems like you should make `xs` an array instead of a list. Or, use `List.toArray` or `Array.ofList` to convert the list to an array before mutating it in the `Parallel.For`.

Comment: Actually, the whole example looks like a suitable task for PLINQ... :)

Answer (score 0):

1. xs.Length / numProc is rounding down (you're losing elements that way, e.g. 1 / 8 = 0).
2. the last chunk might not be of length `chunkLength` but shorter. You have to reconcile that fact.
3. Shouldn't x1 start at 0, not at 1?

Anyway, use the debugger to inspect the runtime values of variables and you'll find all bugs.

Comment: He won't be able to use the debugger if the code doesn't compile. He's getting an error message from the compiler, not an exception at run-time.